# How to fetch Solana Token Metadata as .JSON Response using Python

Tags: solana-program, solana-py, solscan

I'm trying to create a program in python that takes the address of a Solana token and returns its metadata as a .JSON response. I know how to do it for ETH using the alchemy-sdk, when I found out the alchemy-sdk doesn't support Solana, I tried using a metaplex-sdk solution and a solscan solution, but metaplex-sdk only seems to work for NFTs and the solscan API is giving me issues. The closest I got to a working script is one that fetches account information using solana-py, which looks like this:

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from base58 import b58decode

def get_token_metadata(token_address):

    client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")
        # Convert the base-58 encoded string to binary
    binary_address = b58decode(token_address)

    account_info = client.get_account_info(Pubkey(binary_address))
    return account_info

# Example usage
token_address = 'C7K4Tot6fnnNwhWpqw9H277QPcP56vHAEeXubRHDyCo9'
metadata = get_token_metadata(token_address)
print(metadata)
```

But doesn't return the correct .JSON response (Doesn't return a response containing decimals, ticker symbol, socials, etc.). This is the response I get:

```
GetAccountInfoResp { 
context: RpcResponseContext { 
slot: 239683013, api_version: Some("1.17.14") 
}, 
value: Some(Account(Account { 
lamports: 350706442, data.len: 82, owner: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA, executable: false, rent_epoch: 0, data: 00000000502b07546b97b41b1d8d175e8f8f5b862cb3ca86f5381a7a2b721210160ac157e21f57fce00ac78a060100000000502b07546b97b41b1d8d175e8f8f 
})) 
}
```

The only thing I can think of is modifying the script above to pull the PDA, but I don't know how to do that with solana-py. If anybody can provide some assistance it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the metaplex sdk that facilitates this type of stuff only exists for js.
alternatively you can use the quicknode or magic eden api to query directly.